# Event calendar in Angular Material Design

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, angular-material

I want to use Angular Material Design Default Date picker Calendar as a Event Calendar. like: http://prntscr.com/fpg1lw

How can I list my events in calendar?
I just want to highlight some specific dates in Angular Material Design Date picker Calendar.

Comment: See this https://codepen.io/the-teacher/pen/Dkahu

Comment: do you use https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically You cannot accomplish this, but using a little trick may work (if you want only to display the events, not to select a date).

According the doc https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker , you can use **md-date-filter** function(Date): boolean / 
Function expecting a date and returning a boolean whether it can be selected or not.

So you can for example put your date events in an array:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var events = [
  today.getTime(),
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1),
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - 4)
];
$scope.filter = function(Date) {
  return events.indexOf(Date.getTime()) > -1;
};
```

And in your html

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="birthday" md-date-filter="filter" md-is-open="true"></md-datepicker>
```

You will get all the dates disabled except the dates indicated in your events, then add some style to customize it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Fetra, How can I use custom dates instead of (today.getDate() - 4)?

Comment: javascript date but setting hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds to 0 , then use getTime() to compare these date with timestamp https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp eg : var events = [(new Date(2017, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime(), (new Date(2017, 5, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0)).getTime()]

Comment: because month start from 0 (month is from 0-11). just add -1 if you could